# Haskell thread doesn't die

Tags: multithreading, haskell, gloss

I'm using [gloss](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss) to display something, while at the same time using `forkOS $ system "mpg123 foo.mp3" >> return ()` to play some audio in the background. When I close the gloss window, the program exits, but the audio keeps playing. All resources show that this thread is supposed to die, what's going on? It doesn't die even when I use `killThread` to kill it explicitly.

Comment: The `system` function in general isn't interruptible.  If you want killing the thread to terminate a spawned process, you can try catching the asynchronous `ThreadKilled` exception, call `terminateProcess`, then re-throw `ThreadKilled`.

Comment: If I close the gloss window, the main process dies...so in that case `system` should die too, right? If I try this without gloss, the sound stops as expected. And if I kill the program with a ctrl-c on the command line, the sound stops too.

Comment: "If I close the gloss window, the main process dies..." - have you verified that part - does the main process really die and not appear in the process list?

Comment: @JohnL perhaps you should post your comment as an answer...